# Salesforce REST API: query with date in where clause

Tags: rest, salesforce

I am using salesforce REST API to retrieve all the accounts. Something like this:

```
..."/query?q=select+name,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+cust_number__c+!=null"
```

I need to retrieve the delta records once a day. So I am planning to use 'lastmodifiedDate'. Retrieve any record where the lastmodifiedDate is greater than my last pull. But I am getting an error

```
.../query?q=select+name,+CreatedDate+,+lastmodifiedDate,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+lastmodifiedDate+%3e+2017-04-03T20:12:37.000+0000;

Query was unsuccessful. Status code returned is 400
An error has occured. Http status: 400
[ {
  "message" : "\nlastmodifiedDate > 2017-04-03T20:12:37.000 0000\n                                         ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:159\nline 1:159 no viable alternative at character ' '",
  "errorCode" : "MALFORMED_QUERY"
} ]
```

when I try this query:

```
    .../query?q=select+name,+CreatedDate+,+lastmodifiedDate,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+lastmodifiedDate+>+2017-04-03T20:12:37.000+0000;

    Query URL: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 190:

    Exception for '>'
```

How can I get results with date in the where clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to encode the '+' in the time as well. So the final query is

```
 .../query?q=select+name,+CreatedDate+,+lastmodifiedDate,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+lastmodifiedDate+%3e+2017-04-03T20:12:37.000+0000
```